# How to add PATH to ClientConnection gRPC?

Tags: ios, swift, grpc, grpc-swift

I am using grpc to communicate with the server. I create connection using

```
let channel = ClientConnection
                  .secure (group: MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup (numberOfThreads: 10))
                  .connect (host: "testHost.com", port: 443)
```

But with the new version, the connection was moved to https://testHost.com/api,
 **how do I add the** path = **api to connect to the server?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't route gRPC services to a non-root path.

You may need to ask the folks that made the endpoint change, how you can access `/api` but one solution may be to have them create e.g. `api.testhost.com` for gRPC clients.

Answer (score 0):

This path will be present in the protobuffs that are converted to swift lang